# How do you determine the MAC address on a CR-48?

Tags: mac-address, google-chrome-os, cr-48

You get a CR-48 in the mail. You want to use it but the wireless network only allows access to specified MAC addresses. How do you determine the MAC address?

Comment: Since you have access to the network configuration (to allow your new device), turn off MAC filtering for a minute, connect, and sift through the list of connected devices, get the MAC, add it to the list of allowed devices, and re-enable filtering.

Answer (score 8):

Type:

`chrome:///system`

Look for 'ifconfig' and select expand. You'll see 'wlan0'. 'HWaddr' is the MAC address.

Comment: Looks like this may or may not work if you're disconnected: http://code.google.com/p/chromium-os/issues/detail?id=10032

Comment: Good catch Shinrai.

Answer (score 0):

In what is probably a more recent development since you originally asked this question, you can see the MAC from the settings pop-up in the lower right corner. Click the clock, then on "Connected to [SSID]". In the lowest right-hand corner of that popup is an "i" button that looks like a stop sign with the hover text "Network Info". Clicking on it reveals the IP and MAC.

Answer (score 0):

Since ChromeOS 33 (possibly earlier) you go to `chrome://settings`, click the Advanced Settings link at the bottom, then click through Network Proxy Settings to bring up the dialog box. The MAC address is in there, possibly behind a tab.

[This link](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/96815?hl=en) is not Chrome OS specific but the general process is similar.

On my Samsung ARM Chromebook (1st gen) I can click the little Wi-Fi icon in the corner, select the network I'm currently on, and then click the "network" tab, which takes me to the same place.